# Htaccess url rewrite add ?/

Tags: .htaccess

How to url rewrite so pages that would look like `http://example.com/test.php` will appear like `http://example.com/index.php?/test` instead?

This is what I got

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php?/([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @anubhava yes it is

Comment: ok, do you want to rewrite every `.php` file or just `test.php`?

Comment: @anubhava every .php :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work, unfortunately (it only shows the index.php and test.php shows index.php)

Comment: As per your question `http://example.com/test.php` should be forwarded to `http://example.com/index.php?/test` and that is what this rule does.